# How to have Angular2 child routes without a prohibitively long url

Tags: angular2-routing

I have the following configuration for my Angular2 routes...

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
          path: '',
          // redirectTo: '/admin',
          component: LoginComponent,
          pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
          path: "admin",
          component: ContentComponent,
          children: [
              {
                  path:"admin",
                  component: HeaderComponent,
                  outlet: 'header'
              },
              {
                  path:"admin",
                  component: LeftNavComponent,
                  outlet: 'header'
              },
              {
                  path:"admin",
                  component: AdminComponent,
                  outlet: 'body'
              }
          ]
      }
  ])
```

This works good but I don't really need a path for the children and the navigation (`["/admin", {outlets: {"header":["admin"], "body":["admin"], "leftNav":["admin"]}}];`) and the url (`#/admin/(header:admin//body:admin//leftNav:admin)`) are really long. Since I can infer the children is there a way I can leave them out?

Answer (score 0):

When I upgraded from @angular/router v3.1.2 to v3.2.0 it started working as I would expect.